# When I am trying to install bob.db.msu-mfsd-mod and bob.db.replay, an error occurred. How can I fix it?

Tags: database

When I am trying to install bob.db.msu-mfsd-mod and bob.db.replay, this error occurred - how can I fix it?

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Extension' from 'bob.extension' (/private/var/folders/nx/57kfwtj15jx6r76w_6j9y48m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-x4mbkrc_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bob/extension/**init**.py)
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Extension' from 'bob.extension' (/private/var/folders/nx/57kfwtj15jx6r76w_6j9y48m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-x4mbkrc_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bob/extension/**init**.py)